# SQL - Only UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraints can be created on computed columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a table with a computed column called profileID, however when I try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Profiles 
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [profileID] AS ((id * 19379 - 62327) % 99991) NOT NULL
)
```

However when I goto create it, I get this error:

> Only UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraints can be created on computed columns, while CHECK, FOREIGN KEY, and NOT NULL constraints require that computed columns be persisted.

I've tried to adjust the profileID line to this

```
[profileID] as ( (id * 19379 - 62327) % 99991) NOT NULL UNIQUE
```

But I still get the same error.

FYI I have another column called id and its the primary key and is unique and auto_incremented.

Comment: The error message is very clear - You can only use unique or primary key constraints on a computed column. You can't create a computed column with a `not null` constraint unless it's persisted.
However, in your case that should not be a problem since your calculation is based on hard coded values and a not null column, so the result of that calculation can't be null anyway.

Comment: You either have to remove `NOT NULL` or make the computed column persisted. This is what the error message essentially says.

Comment: How do I fix it @ZoharPeled

Comment: Like  Giorgos Betsos wrote - either create it as persisted or simply remove the not null.

Comment: Umm, NOT "clear" in my case. I had the opposite prob: creating Computed Column (CC) that's Persisted and Nullable. Apparently, you can't specify Null on a Computed Column period (Persisted or not). Apparently, Null is the default Constraint on a CC, BUT: a) that doesn't explain why it can't be specified (cuz it can be on non-CCs even though it's the default on them) AND b) instead of "'wasting'" "'precious'" dev & mem costs on a more appro err like "Null is the default on a CC.", it reported this lazy cryptic catch-all err. (In Capt. Kirk's voice in Wrath of Khan): "~bbbbbbbbbBILLLLLLLLLL~!!!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is very clear - You can only use unique or primary key constraints on a computed column. You can't create a computed column with a not null constraint unless it's persisted.

So either create that column as `persisted`:

```
CREATE TABLE Profiles 
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [profileID] as ( (id * 19379 - 62327) % 99991) PERSISTED NOT NULL
)
```

Or simply remove the `not null` (it's never going to be null anyway)

```
CREATE TABLE Profiles 
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [profileID] as ( (id * 19379 - 62327) % 99991) 
)
```

Comment: I had the opposite prob: creating Computed Column (CC) that's `Persisted` and Nullable.  Apparently, you can't specify Null on a Computed Column period (`Persisted` or not).  Apparently, Null is the default Constraint on a CC, BUT: a) that doesn't explain why it can't be specified (cuz it can be on non-CCs even though it's the default on them) AND b) instead of "'wasting'" "'precious'" dev & mem costs on a more appro err like "Null is the default on a CC.", it reported this lazy cryptic catch-all err.  (In Capt. Kirk's voice in Wrath of Khan): "~bbbbbbbbbBILLLLLLLLLL~!!!"