# Why is Entity Framework generating the [Required] attribute on my computed column?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Simplified example: I have a computed column defined as a field in my Azure SQL server table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] 
(
  [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  [CancelledOn] DATETIME NULL,
  [MyComputedColumn] AS CASE WHEN ([CancelledOn] IS NOT NULL) THEN 'Cancelled' ELSE 'Draft' END
)
```

But when I generate a code-first ADO.NET Entity Data Model in Visual Studio 2017, the property gets generated with both `[Required]` and `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` attributes.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
[Required]
[StringLength(19)]
public string MyComputedColumn { get; set; }
```

Of course, this then causes entity validation errors and various other problems.

Why would EF mark this property as `[Required]` when it also knows that it's a computed field?

I understand I can just delete the attribute, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution than having to manually delete the `[Required]` attribute from all my computed columns every time I regenerate my entity model.  Can I declare the column differently in SQL, for example?

Comment: Have you tried with adding NULL with computer column ?

Comment: By the logic of MyComputedColumn its a not null, so EF marked it as required.

Comment: @Zain Apparently I can't... SQL46011: Only Unique or Primary Key constraints can be created on computed columns, while Check, Foreign Key, and Not Null constraints require that computed columns be persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Even though we know the computed column can never be null by the logic you used, EF is not that smart, so you should make the computed column nullable even though it will never be null.

Comment: I tried to make it nullable but couldn't... SQL46011: Only Unique or Primary Key constraints can be created on computed columns, while Check, Foreign Key, and Not Null constraints require that computed columns be persisted.  Is this supposed to be possible?  If so, how?

Comment: Yes, you can persist the computed column: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45727264/2283168

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Shan's comment for nudging me in the right direction:

> By the logic of MyComputedColumn its a not null, so EF marked it as
>   required.

I couldn't just make the column NULLABLE as others suggested, so I had to add an impossible NULL case to the computed column:

```
[MyComputedColumn] AS CASE 
  WHEN 2 = 1 THEN NULL 
  WHEN [CancelledOn] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Cancelled' 
  ELSE 'Draft' END
```

It's a bit of a hack and I wish EF was smarter, but it no longer generates `[Required]`, so it works for my purposes.